# pandas not found with python3 command but able to run with python command

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, modulenotfounderror

I have a simple script to read a data and a model and compute score on it.

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

with open('samplemodel.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    model = pickle.load(file)

testdata=pd.read_csv('testdata_l3demo.csv')
X = testdata[['bed','bath']].values.reshape(-1,2)
y = testdata['highprice'].values.reshape(-1,1)

predicted=model.predict(X)

f1score=metrics.f1_score(predicted,y)
print(f1score)
```

If I run the above script with `python3 script.py`, it shows me this error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`. But if I run `python script.py`, it works perfectly fine.
I tried to `pip list` and am able to see `pandas 1.4.3`.
I am on MacOS and not in any virtual env.
This does not affect anything so far, but I would love to know why and how to fix this.
thank you

Comment: maybe you have two seperate python installed , python 3 and python 2 each one has its own libraries installed

Comment: See if you see `pandas` in `pip3 list` as well

Comment: this is what i see with `pip3 list`. 
```
Package       Version
------------- --------
cffi          1.15.0
cryptography  36.0.1
numpy         1.21.4
opencv-python 4.5.4.60
pdf2image     1.16.0
peewee        3.14.9
Pillow        8.4.0
pip           22.1.1
protobuf      3.19.4
pycparser     2.21
PyMySQL       1.0.2
pytesseract   0.3.8
setuptools    62.3.2
six           1.16.0
tabulate      0.8.9
wheel         0.37.1
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

Comment: so, no `pandas` ? You can probably do a `pip3 install pandas` - but I would suggest taking a look at virtual environments before doing a global install.

Comment: Can you please explain what's the difference here? pip vs pip3 and pip vs python version.
Why `pip list` and `pip3 list` have completely different output? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 major versions of the Python programming language - python 2 and python 3 - you can find more information [here](https://python3statement.org/).

Python 2 has been officially discontinued, but stays around for legacy reasons (to support software that has been built on and uses python 2). It also stays on on some OS'es as the default version of python.

Python 3 is where all the latest and greatest developments are happening.

If you do not have a specific, compelling reason to use Python 2 - you should stick with Python 3.

On Operating Systems where both Python 2 and Python 3 are installed, you can distinguish between the two versions with the `3` suffix - e.g. `python3` or `pip3` or `ipython3` etc. In other words, `pip install xx` would install a python 2 version of the package whereas a `pip3 install xx` would install a python 3 version.